# Does concurrent read cause overhead?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Assume in C# multithreading programming, we have a global, shared class object `O`. Multiple threads can read various readonly fields of `O` concurrently (i.e. no write, only read). Does this introduce extra overhead or the read performance is expected to as fast as single-threaded read?

Comment: It is [technically possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), you'd have to be quite unlucky in the given scenario.  Be sure to measure.

Comment: @HansPassant to my knowledge sharing overhead only occurs on writes, not reads, otherwise I'd have noted it. Do you know of any architectures this happens on?

Comment: You are overlooking static variables of another type that are adjacent in memory, still in the same cache line, and that get written to.  You have no direct control over the storage address, so there isn't much point in worrying about it.  Only consider padding if you measured to *know* you got a problem.

Comment: But even with other things in the cache line, *reading* specifically would still not have overhead. Only writing would incur false sharing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple read will have no overhead.

A read where you need to enforce memory ordering might. A `volatile` field or use of `Volatile.Read` can have overhead both in terms of the specific individual operation but also by preventing some optimizations on surrounding code, because it has acquire semantics.